# Textblob word tokenization into array

Tags: arrays, tokenize, textblob

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import nltk
array=("i have a bunch of grapes","i like to eat apple","this is a laptop")
array2=[]



for i in array:

    c=TextBlob(i)
    array2.append(c.words)

print array2
```

the result printed out will be:

> > [WordList(['i', 'have', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'grapes']), WordList(['i', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'apple']), WordList(['this', 'is', 'a', 'laptop'])]

how can i extract from the WordList so that my array2 will be printed as:

> > [['i', 'have', 'a', 'bunch', 'of', 'grapes'],['i', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'apple'],["this is a laptop"]]

Answer (score 1):

You can **list()** it before appending to the array2:

```
for i in array:
    c=TextBlob(i)
    array2.append(list(c.words))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array2.append(c.words._collection)
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)